# Asynchronously Publish to Observable/Subject

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

While I think I've got a handle on the basics of how to use RxJava, I'm having trouble using the Observer pattern.

Basically, what I want to do is have a static `List` of objects that I can monitor, and use additions to the list to submit this data to a webservice.

My approach so far has to just been create a `static List<Object>` and a `static Observable<Object>`. This observable is created by just doing a

```
observable = Observable.from(listOfObjects);
```

Then, I have my upload logic inside of a `.subscribe()` call. This would work if I had the `List` all set up ahead of time, but I want to populate it here and there at runtime. This will still work if I call `.subscribe()` again, but it feels like I am doing something wrong by doing that. I thought I could get the existing subscription to just act on any new items emitted from the observable, but nothing seems to be happening when I add to the list.

Any insight on a better/correct approach is appreciated.

Comment: I am very curious about an answer to this, I'd definitely use it too. I think RxJava doesn't have any solution per se, what we want is basically something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260746 or http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post1941_perishable-collections-the-benefits-of-removal-by-lifetime

Comment: dwursteisen's answer is correct. You have to create a wrapper around a `List` that will notify Subscribers when items are added or removed from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.from(listOfObjects)` will create a new observable that will emit each of list's objects. You can write `Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)` too. It's the same thing.

So, if you add an object into your list, the `Observable` won't be notified.

You can create a custom list that will notify your `Observable` from a new added item. You will see a very close solution to his in topic : [How can I create an Observer over a dynamic list in RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816691/how-can-i-create-an-observer-over-a-dynamic-list-in-rxjava/28835815#28835815)

But, you can ride of your list and maybe use a [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject) instead ? Instead of adding object to your list, just call `theSubject.onNext` method.

Please note that you only be notified when item will be added. You won't be notified when items are removed. If you want to, your `Observable` shouldn't emit added item but item, with an associated state : `new Added<Object>(item)`, `new Removed<Object>(item)` for example.

Comment: This works well for me. It still feel like there should be a slightly less verbose approach, but that is probably just a lack of understanding on my part. :)